# How to secure a PDF so recipient must open with a password, and then may save it without one

Tags: pdf, password-protection

Is there a way for the original sender to password protect the PDF they send me (where I must use the password to *open* the document)

**but**

-also- allows me to save a copy (or print-to-PDF), locally, which does not later require that same password -- whether by me to open it locally, or by others to whom I elect to send the saved document ?

I receive PDFs from the Fed Government which are password protected (which password they email to me in a separate email).   I am able to open, save and print the documents - with the password.

The PDFs are often documents which I must send on to other folks, as clear PDFs (without a password).  I usually open PDFs with adobe's reader, but use from time to time NitroReader 3.  I typically print-to-PDF, to a local folder, using PDFCreator.

When I save my [opened and local] copy of the document, it retains the password setting, and similarly does so if I print the relevant page to a PDF printer on my WinBox.  Thus I must save for a year, and distribute, that password for that specific document.

My current work around is annoying -- I have to take a snippet of the PDF, then print that snippet to a JPG, which I then print to a PDF.   Alternatively, I could print out the color document to a B&W printer, and physically scan the B&W paper to a PDF -- also annoying.

Suggestions ?

Comment: Once the document has been protected to require a password, I do not believe that can removed without, effectively, recreating the document, which is what your various workarounds all are about.

Comment: it depends on what options are locked by the password (should be pretty much all of them if they're putting a password on it in the first place), but depending on your .PDF reader you may be able to flatten the entire .PDF, which will remove the protection - but also all of the interactable elements (text boxes, buttons, etc.) - so those are also some factors in what your options will be. If you add what kind of elements and/or what kinds of options are available in your reader, and your .PDF program that might be helpful for potential answers.

Comment: What about putting it in a password-protected archive, like a zip file?  Password extracts the PDF, then they can do what they need with it.

Comment: On a side note: the creators of the .PDF are likely password protecting the file because they have no way of getting it to you via encrypted e-mail - an alternative approach (if you have a good point of contact) may be to simply find out if the password is actually necessary and see if they can send it to you without it via some other relatively secure method like AMRDEC or ARL Safe. Regardless, use best practices when disseminating sensitive information.

Comment: @mael' -- FEMA requires an email with the PWD protected PDF, and a separate, unsecured email with the PWD -- where there is personally identifiable information in the PDF.   I am -specifically- curious if there is a specific protection setting that the creator of the PDF can use, which mael' alludes to in his first note, that might protect the PDF, but allow me my access as I like.   I note: mael's comment and music2myear's comment are opposite perspectives.   The suggestion by fixer1234 might make sense, but they just don't do that.

Comment: It's disappointing that they send both PDF and the key to unlock it via the same, unsecured medium. If it's PII they can use AMRDEC to just send the .PDF with no password, but I sympathize with the prospect of asking people to change the way they've been doing something. Music's and my answers aren't opposite - they both boil down to how much you want to break the PDF. Regardless, if you have the password and are using anything above Adobe Reader you should be able to remove the password protection from the Security section of Properties. I don't believe there's a setting on the creator's side

Comment: @mael' -- thanks for your comments.   I note this:  FEMA requires the method when sending documents to the general population.  The odds are most would have no idea what AMRDEC is, nor would they have the skill to use it . . . Similarly, that same population receiving the PDFs might get confused on ways to use a ZIP file.    Another FYI -- the document I get has my own info on it, and is a FEMA/NFIP certification document that I have to send to adjusting firms.   I do wonder if FEMA uses a master password to prohibit unlocking the document using Adobe Acrobat -- I don't own it, and can't test.

Comment: Generally if a pdf let's me print it, I can print to pdf using Chrome which creates an unsecured pdf. Example: I just created a PDF version 1.7 with 256-bit AES encryption using PowerPDF. I opened it in Chrome, used the password to open it then printed to pdf with Chrome. Password stripped. Does that not work for these?
I have to do this everyday for work as we receive password protected pdfs (that are not confidential) that need to be modified. I haven't come across a pdf that can't be opened and printed to unsecured pdf with Chrome.